# Set layout on Sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I try to setLayout when the orientation was changed , but I get this type of error :

```
*Console.js:17Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#setLayout] Replacing a layout after one has already been initialized is not currently supported.*
```

and I cannot get, what is going on here. Here is my code :

```
  onOrientationChange:function(viewport, orientation){  
        viewport.setLayout('vbox');
  }
```

where the viewport is :

```
Ext.define("Q4.view.blg", {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype:  'blg',
    config:{    
        title:"blg",
        iconCls:'star',
        cls:'blogList',
        disableSelection: true,
        layout: 'hbox',
        defaults:{
            scrollable:false
        },........
```

Thanks !!!!!!